# Copy an object to a new database in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, multiple-databases

I want to have a method on a class to copy the object and all of the relationships to another database that has the same structure. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Hmm, backup then restore in the new DB?

Comment: We need more detail. Is this a one-time task? Then MrYoshiji’s suggestion works. Will this be done regularly? Are you worried about keeping the objects in sync; if you duplicate the object and its dependents once and a second time, will you need to overwrite the original copy?

Comment: I'm not worried about synchronizing the objects. I just want to push them into another database when an action occurs. Firing the action a second time would overwrite the objects in the second database. This would happen on a per object basis.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could have a look at [dbcharmer](http://dbcharmer.net/), which will allow to switch connections on the fly, so copying a record would be a piece of cake I guess.

[UPDATE] Small example: you do not have to mess with the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`

Suppose your `database.yml` looks like this:

```
production:
  blah:
    adapter: mysql
    username: blah
    host: blah.local
    database: blah

  foo:
    adapter: mysql
    username: foo
    host: foo.local
    database: foo
```

Then you should be able to do something like (disclaimer: I only read the documentation myself)

```
original_user = User.on_foo.find(99)

User.on_blah.create(name: original_user.name, ...)
```

I guess you could even do something like

```
User.on_blah do 
  original_user.save
end
```

Comment: I looked at dbcharmer but I don't want it to mess up ActiveRecord::Base's connection or the connection of other objects of the same class.

Comment: As I read the documentation there is no need to mess with the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`, but you can just perform statements for a specific connection, using the `.on_<connection-name>` command. I added a small example.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the way to go. I need to duplicate data from all of the relationships on the object as well. I am running into problems with mass assignment, validations, and relationships.

Comment: In that case Shouldn't you consider something a little more low level, on database level? Like a script, or import/export? It is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve for me. Maybe use an api? Sync databases, with master/slave?

Comment: True. I was thinking about having some SQL do it or using an API.

Comment: I could just use the mysql adapter directly and generate a bulk insert statement.